# React-Navigation increase swipe back area

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, gesture

I am using the React-Navigation lib for my current project and dont like the swipe back function. It only gets triggered if you place your finger at the total edge of the screen for the gesture to swipe back. I have read the [API Reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html) but could not found anything towards my problem with the behaviour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can increase swipe back area with this:

```
const stack = createStackNavigator({
   Home,
   ...
}, {
   ...
   navigationOptions: {
      gestureResponseDistance: {horizontal: 100} // default is 25
   }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Just an updated answer for react navigation v5 / `gestureResponseDistance`

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


// ...in render() method
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
    <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} options={{ gestureResponseDistance: { vertical: 200, horizontal: 150 } }} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#gestureresponsedistance

or use `screenOptions` prop on `<Navigator>` for all screens:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator mode="modal" screenOptions={{ gestureResponseDistance: { vertical: 200, horizontal: 150 } }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```